# Installing ModX on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

Apologies for a probably very basic question. But I'm trying to install ModX and the tutorials I can find on this go into how to set up the website. I'm using a site on an existing server. Do I need to do any of this stuff? What are the basic steps I need to take to get this program running?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See here for the standard ModX installation instructions: 
https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/getting-started/installation

The following instruction also looks very complete: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-modx-cms-on-ubuntu-17-04-17-10-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-support/

Needed before installing ModX: Apache or NGINX, PHP, MySQL or MariaDB (check the server requirements: https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/getting-started/server-requirements)

download the software of MODX, for example by using:

```
wget https://modx.com/download/direct?id=modx-2.6.5-pl.zip
```

unzip the file and copy the contents to your wished directory (xxxx), create some directories and set some rights (this might be a bit overkill):

```
unzip modx-2*
cd modx-2*
cp -R * /var/www/xxxx
cp ht.access /var/www/xxxx/.htaccess
cd /var/www/xxxx
mkdir assets
mkdir assets/components
mkdir assets/files
mkdir core/components
touch core/config/config.inc.php
chgrp -R www-data *
chown -R www-data *
chmod -R 750 *
chmod -R 770 core/packages
chmod -R 770 core/cache
chmod -R 770 core/export
chmod -R 770 core/components
chmod 770 core/config/config.inc.php
chmod -R 770 manager
chmod -R 770 assets
chmod -R 770 connectors
cd ..
chgrp -R www-data xxxx
chmod 770 xxxx
```

Create a database for the ModX site with general_CI and create a userid that has the right to create tables in the database.

setup the handling of the relevant domain in Apache (https://websiteforstudents.com/install-modx-cms-on-ubuntu-17-04-17-10-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-support/) or NGINX (https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/getting-started/installation/basic-installation/nginx-server-config).

Run the ModX setup; just go to the link for the site with added "/setup", something like:

```
http://xxxx.com/setup
```

Make sure that the setup software is removed (if not already done by setup-software):

```
cd /var/www/xxxx
rm -r setup
```

And make sure that the configuration file is not editable anymore (if not already done by setup-software):

```
cd core/config
chmod 440 config.inc.php
```